# How do I convert 1D data into a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have downloaded some aeromagnetic data and am trying to plot it using `pcolor` or `pcolormesh`. This data came in a format where each column had a type of data. I read the file and took out the longitude, latitude and background magnetic columns. So I have 3 1D arrays with these values. To plot with `pcolor` I need the magnetic array to be 2D. I was wondering what the best way to convert the array or if there is some better method of plotting with 1D arrays.

```
Long = np.genfromtxt('AZ_5041.txt', usecols = 2)
Lat = np.genfromtxt('AZ_5041.txt', usecols = 3)
Mag = np.genfromtxt('AZ_5041.txt', usecols = 9)
```

Comment: Have you tried np.reshape?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like vstack (or a related method).

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html